# extract tidyr function with Regex: bracket and commas as separator

Tags: r, tidyr

Here is my dataset:

```
df = data.frame(x=c(NA, "xxdsa[1,d]", "x[a,3]", "x2[a,d]", "x4[a,4]"))
```

df:

```
           x
1       <NA>
2 xxdsa[1,d]
3     x[a,3]
4    x2[a,d]
5    x4[a,4]
```

I want to separate the x column into 3 columns, with either the bracket or the comma as separators. The result should be:

```
      A    B    C
1  <NA> <NA> <NA>
2 xxdsa    1    d
3     x    a    3
4    x2    a    d
5    x4    a    4
```

I tried the following code but do not understand why it's not working. I really want to use the extract function from tidyr as it is quite fast (compared to the separate function for example).

```
df %>% tidyr::extract(x, c("A", "B","C"), "([[a-zA-Z0-9]]+)\\[([[a-zA-Z0-9]]+)\\,([[a-zA-Z0-9]]+)\\]")
```

Comment: In the future, a great tool for this is to put your regex into https://regex101.com. It'll explain what's going on and let you test and debug it. The one wrinkle is that in R, you have to double the escape character (so `\\ ` ) while in others it's just a single `\ `

Comment: @akrun I know, that part has nothing to do with their problem. I'm just warning them that if they want to put their regex in a regex tester, they'll have to replace their \\ with \ during testing or they'll get an error

Comment: @divibisan sorry, I did see some escape in their code, so was thinking that the OP mistakenly used the `[[` instead of `[`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to match the regex correctly - in the below code, from the start (`^`) of the string, capture one or more characters that are not an opening square bracket (`([^\\[]+)`) followed by the opening square bracket (`\\[` - escaped as it is metacharacter), then capture the second group that are not a comma (`([^,]+)`), followed by the `,`  and the last group not the closing bracket (`([^\\]]+)`) followed  by the closing bracket (`\\]`)

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df, x, into = c("A", "B", "C"), "^([^\\[]+)\\[([^,]+),([^\\]]+)\\]")
```

-output

```
      A    B    C
1  <NA> <NA> <NA>
2 xxdsa    1    d
3     x    a    3
4    x2    a    d
5    x4    a    4
```

---

In the OP's code, just take out the `a-zA-Z0-9` from the `[[` and place it inside `[`

```
df %>% 
  tidyr::extract(x, c("A", "B","C"), 
   "^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\[([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\,([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\]")
      A    B    C
1  <NA> <NA> <NA>
2 xxdsa    1    d
3     x    a    3
4    x2    a    d
5    x4    a    4
```

According to `?regex`

> ‘⁠[[:alnum:]]⁠’ means ‘⁠[0-9A-Za-z]⁠’,

Answer (score 1):

I tried a different regular expression, please check

```r
tidyr::extract(df, x,into=c('A','B','C'), regex = '(\\w.*)\\[(.*)\\,(.*)\\]', remove = F)
```